# MySQL / PHP background image URL 2

Tags: php, mysql, css

I have a little problem with a php/sql backgroung-image.
My code is

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo
        '<div>',
            '<div>',
                '<a href="#">',
                '<div class="coupimage" style="background-image: url("'.$row['img_5'].'");"></div></a>',
                '<br />',
                '<h3>'.$row['var1'].'</h3>', '<br />',
                $row['var2'],', ',
                $row['var3'],'<br />',
                $row['var4'],', ',
                $row['var5'], '<br />',
            '</div>',
        '</div>';
}
```

It work good for each "var" but background-image don't work.

```
echo $row['img_5'];
```

print correct link and if I use

```
'<img src="'.$row['img_5'].'">'
```

work great too but in style class it return image link without "/" and it don't work.

ex http://www.example.org/image.jpg -> http: www.example.org image.jpg

What I have to do?

Comment: Sidenote: Stop using [`mysql_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) functions. They've been out of date for a very long time, and are officially deprecated. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: Either show your url of any image or check my answer,.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace space to "/"

```
// $str == $row['img_5']
// It will work if we got an space

$str = "http: www.example.org image.jpg";

$arr = explode(" ", $str);

$url = $arr[0]."/".$arr[1];
```

In ur case :

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $arr = explode(" ", $row['img_5']);
        $url = $arr[0]."/".$arr[1];

        echo
        '<div>',
            '<div>',
                '<a href="#">',
                '<div class="coupimage" style="background-image: url("'.$url.'");"></div></a>',
                '<br />',
                '<h3>'.$row['var1'].'</h3>', '<br />',
                $row['var2'],', ',
                $row['var3'],'<br />',
                $row['var4'],', ',
                $row['var5'], '<br />',
            '</div>',
        '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation with your answer to avoid deletion